# Как проверить, что переменная состоит из 5 цифр

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача проверить состоит ли переменная из 5 цифр, если Да вернуть True.

```
def is_valid_zipcode(self):
   if  self.__zipcode.is_integer() and self.__zipcode > 9999:
       return True
   else: return False
```

Можно использовать регулярки

(Данный код выдает ошибку !)
if  self.__zipcode.is_integer() and self.__zipcode > 9999:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'is_integer'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Раз в `self.__zipcode` уже `int`, то не нужно проверять что это число, а достаточно проверить диапазон:

```
def is_valid_zipcode(self):
    return self.__zipcode > 9999 and self.__zipcode <= 99999
```

Кст, подобную проверку можно сделать через `range`:

```
    return self.__zipcode in range(9999 + 1, 99999 + 1)
```

---

Если бы вы работали со строками, тогда проверяйте что в строке только цифры и что ее длина 5:

```
zipcode = '12345'
print(zipcode.isdigit() and len(zipcode) == 5)
```

Comment: Дело в том, я же не знаю, что пользователю стрелнит в голове ввести) Мне нужно проверить и на то, что это число и на то, что оно состоит из 5 чисел

Comment: @Daniil, это да. При указании значения `self.__zipcode` приводите его к числу. Либо в `is_valid_zipcode` добавьте условие, что если в `self.__zipcode` строка, то обработка <такая>, иначе проверка через диапазон

Comment: через range наверное не очень оптимально, это же все значения будут генерироваться

Comment: @Эникейщик, неа, `range` знает границы и не будет при `in` генерировать все значения

Comment: @Эникейщик Это в Python 2 так было бы, а в Python 3 `range` - это специальный умный объект с кучей клёвых оптимизаций, в том числе и проверки на вхождение

Answer (score -1):

[is_integer](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/is_integer.html) - метод класса `float`.

```
>>> (1).is_integer()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'is_integer'
```

---

```
>>> (1.0).is_integer()
True
>>>
```

Comment: это для какой-то другой задачи решение, а не для этой